# Retornar colunas que aceitam boolean em uma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necessito de uma *query* que traga o nome das colunas em uma tabela que aceitam `boolean`. Ex: Na tabela `clientes`, tenho os campos `casapropria` (1 para sim, 0 para nao), `temfilhos` (1 para sim, 0 para não).

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'clientes' AND data_type = 'bit'
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Boolean.sql).

Answer (score 1):

Galera, 
Acabei conseguindo. Segue caso lhe seja útil
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]